# Have error Livewire encountered corrupt data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm using extends in Laravel Livewire.

It can display, but when I want to add or change data, I got an error.

> Livewire encountered corrupt data when trying to hydrate the [crud.add-student-component] component. Ensure that the [name, id, data] of the Livewire component wasn't tampered with between requests.

So I do solution from this
[Livewire encountered corrupt data when trying to hydrate the … component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63848826/livewire-encountered-corrupt-data-when-trying-to-hydrate-the-component) to change public to protected.

Then I got the error that I don't have a public property.

> Unable to set component data. Public property [$name] not found on component: [crud.add-student-component]

This is in the blade.

```
@extends('components.hide')   
@section('add')
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .text-center{

        }
        .container{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            width: 200%;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
   
<div>
 {{-- @extends('livewire.crud.edit-student-component') --}}

 {{-- @extends('livewire.crud.index-component') --}}

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center mt-5">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Add New Student</h5>
                        <a href="{{ route('students') }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="float:right;">All Students</a>
                  
                    </div>


                    <div class="card-body">
                        @if (session()->has('message'))
                            <div class="alert alert-success text-center">{{ session ('message') }}</div>
                            
                        @endif

                        <form wire:submit.prevent="storeStudent"> 
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="student_id">Student ID</label>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" wire:model="student_id"/>
                                {{-- this is  validation --}}
                                @error('student_id')
                                    <span class="text-danger" style="font-size: 12.5px;">{{ $message }}</span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name">Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" wire:model="name"/>
                                {{-- this is  validation --}}
                                @error('name')
                                    <span class="text-danger" style="font-size: 12.5px;">{{ $message }}</span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">Email</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" wire:model="email"/>
                                {{-- this is  validation --}}
                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="text-danger" style="font-size: 12.5px;">{{ $message }}</span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" wire:model="phone"/>
                                {{-- this is  validation --}}
                                @error('phone')
                                    <span class="text-danger" style="font-size: 12.5px;">{{ $message }}</span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="image">Image</label>
                                <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control" wire:model="image"/>
                                {{-- this is  validation --}}
                                @error('image')
                                    <span class="text-danger" style="font-size: 12.5px;">{{ $message }}</span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        

                        

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="birth">Birth</label>
                                <input type="datetime"  id="datepickerlink"

                                
                                class="form-control" wire:model="birth"/>
                                {{-- this is  validation --}}
                                @error('birth')
                                    <span class="text-danger" style="font-size: 12.5px;">{{ $message }}</span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>





                            <div class="form-group text-center">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm w-50">Add Student</button>
                            </div>
                             
                            <link href="dist/css/datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
                            <script src="dist/js/datepicker.min.js"></script>
                    
                            <!-- Include English language -->
                            <script src="dist/js/i18n/datepicker.en.js"></script>

                            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
                            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>
                            

                            <script>
                            flatpickr("input[type='datetime']", {});

                            </script>





                            </div>

                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
@endsection
```

This in the controller.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Crud;



use App\Models\Student;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;



use Livewire\Component;

 class AddStudentComponent extends Component
 {
use WithFileUploads;

//change form public to protected
protected $student_id, $name, $email, $phone, $birth, $image, $students, $user_id;





public function field()
{
   
    $this->validateOnly( [
        'student_id' => 'required|unique:students',
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:students',
        'phone' => 'required|numeric|unique:students',
        'image' => 'required|image|:students',
        'birth' => 'required|:students',

    ]);

    dd($this->image);

    if(!empty($this->image)){
        $this->image->store('public/image');

        dd($this->image);
    }

    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    $student = new Student();

    $student->student_id = $this->student_id;
    $student->name = $this->name;
    $student->email = $this->email;
    $student->phone = $this->phone;
    $student->image = $this->image;
    $student->birth = $this->birth;

    $student->save();

    session()->flash('message', 'Student has been added successfully');

    $this->student_id = '';
    $this->name = '';
    $this->email = '';
    $this->phone = '';
    $this->image = '';
    $this->birth = '';

   


}



public function storeStudent(){

  
   
    $this->validate([
        'student_id' => 'required|unique:students',
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:students',
        'phone' => 'required|numeric|unique:students',
        'image' => 'required|unique:students',
        'birth' => 'required|:students',

         
    
         


    ]);
    //

   

    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    $student = new Student();

    $student->student_id = $this->student_id;
    $student->name = $this->name;
    $student->email = $this->email;
    $student->phone = $this->phone;
    $student->image = $this->image;
    $student->birth = $this->birth;

    //

    // if(!empty($this->image)){
    //     $this->image->store('public/image');

    $student->user_id = $user_id;
    //

    $student->image = $this->image->store('image');

    $student->save();

    session()->flash('message', 'Student has been added successfully');

    $this->student_id = '';
    $this->name = '';
    $this->email = '';
    $this->phone = '';
    $this->image = '';
    $this->birth = '';

    

}



public function render()
{
    //adding this from index-component 18/4/22
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $students = Student::where('user_id', $user_id);
    //
    return view('livewire.crud.add-student-component');
}
}
```

This is in the blade extends.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
<style>
    .header {
        background-color:#FF8C32;
        height: 100px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        text-align: center;
    }

    h5 {
        height: 50px;
    }

    .main {
        background-color: #EEEEEE;
        height: 600px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }




    .footer {
        background-color: #06113C ;
        height: 80px;
        text-align: center;
    }


    .slideleft {
       
        width: 200px;
        top: 100;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 80;
        /* height: 600px; */
        background-color: #DDDDDD;
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }

    .slideleft tbody {
        flex-direction: column-reverse;

    }

    .header h5 {
        float: right;
        height: 20px;
    }

    .center {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        width: 50px;
    }

    .logo img{
        padding-top: 10px;
    }

    .note{
        /* place-items: center; */
        /* margin: auto; */
        /* text-align: center; */
        padding: 30px;
        color: #EEEEEE;
    }

</style>


@livewireStyles
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="header">
    <div class="logo">
        <img width="80" 
            src="https://d29fhpw069ctt2.cloudfront.net/icon/image/39129/preview.png"
            alt="picture phonebook">

    </div>
    <div>

        <h5>Addres Book</h5>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="main">

  

    <div class="slideleft">
        <div class="upper">
            <a href="{{ route('addstudents') }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" style="text-align: center;">
                <button>Add New Contact</button>
            </a>
        </div>

        
        {{-- {{ dd($students ?? '') }} --}}
        {{-- @dd($students) --}}
        {{-- <tbody>
            @if ($students->count() > 0)
                @foreach ($students  as $student)
                    <tr>
                       
                        <a href="{{ route ('editstudents', ['id' => $student->id]) }}" wire:click="$emit('showedit')" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary"
                            style="padding: 1px 8px;">
                            <td>{{ $student->name }}</td>
                        </a>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            @else
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" style="text-align: center;">No students found!</td>
                </tr>
            @endif
        </tbody> --}}

        <p>test</p>

    </div>

    <div class="center">

        <h1>check</h1>
        @yield('add')
        @yield('edit')

       
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
   
    <div class="note">
       
        &copy; All rights reserved

    </div>


</div>




@livewireScripts
```

any idea?
hopefully you can answer this to help my struggle