# Livewire encountered corrupt data when trying to hydrate the [inventory] component. Ensure that the [name, id, data] of the Livewire component

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I am facing Some problem, I try to add Search in my Laravel Project Using Livewire model, but this happen. Here My Code :

```
 public $request, $path, $page, $export, $fileName, $pdf, $col, $ids;
    public $qrCodeUrls = [];
    public $perPage = 10;
    public $currentPage = 1;
    public $search;
    protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';

    private $inventory;

    public function render()
    {
        // Define the query without executing it yet
        $query = InventoryTable::orderBy('id', 'asc');

        // Apply the search filter if a search term is entered
        if (!empty($this->search)) {
            $query->where('nama_barang', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%');
        }

        // Paginate the results
        $inventory = $query->paginate(10);

        // Generate QR code URLs for each item
        foreach ($inventory as $item) {
            $this->qrCodeUrls[$item->id] = QrCode::size(400)->generate($item->barcode);
        }

        return view('livewire.inventory', compact('inventory'));
    }


    public function mount($inventory)
    {

        $this->inventory = $inventory;
        // Generate QR code URLs for each item in $inventory
        foreach ($this->inventory as $col) {
            $this->qrCodeUrls[$col->id] = QrCode::size(400)->generate($col->barcode);
        }
    }
```

I don't find any solve, and already try some solved method but it didn't work, this is in my Inventory Livewire Class

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Livewire encountered corrupt data when trying to hydrate the … component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63848826/livewire-encountered-corrupt-data-when-trying-to-hydrate-the-component)